# Should I make project report public before publishing journal article

Tags: publications, plagiarism, self-plagiarism

I have written a report about a piece of user research that was carried out with an industry partner. The partner wants to make the report public, and I would also like it to be public as soon as possible and disseminated widely as it is of interest to the (fast moving) industry.
However, i also plan to write an academic article (which will obviously take longer to publish) based on the research, and am concerned about self-plagiarism.
Should I

1. Wait until after journal publication to make the report public
2. Make the report public and reference it in the article
3. Make the report public and include a reference to the article ("in preparation")

Answer (score 1):

Check the rules of your intended target journal(s) about their rules for posting to a preprint server. Many journals will exempt posting to a well-established preprint server from their rules about pre-publication.

If the rules allow it, post the report to the preprint server (preferably in a form close to that expected for an academic paper, but you can always call it the "first draft"; most preprint servers allow posting of updated versions).